# Ruby on Rails : list children in show view for a self join relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am building a hierarchical Organisations list in my application, using the same principles as for one-to-many joins I used with various objects.

But with this one-to-many self join, I get an error as the SQL generated refers a organisations.organisation_id column that does not exist.

Here are parts of my code:

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :owner_id, presence: true
validates :status_id, presence: true
validates :playground_id, presence: true
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"            # helps retrieving the owner name
belongs_to :status, :class_name => "Parameter", :foreign_key => "status_id"     # helps retrieving the status name
belongs_to :parent_org, :class_name => "Organisation", :foreign_key => "parent_id"  # helps retrieving the parent name
has_many :child_orgs, :class_name => "Organisation"                         # links from the child organisations
```

The routes (I can create an organisation only from its parent):

```
resources :organisations do
     resources :organisations, :only=>[:new, :create]
end
```

The controller:

```
# GET /organisations/1
# GET /organisations/1.json
def show
  @organisation = Organisation.includes(:owner, :status, :parent_org).find(params[:id])
end
```

The extract of the show view listing children of current organisation:

```
<table width=100%>    
  <tr><td><hr /></td></tr>
  <tr align="left">
    <th>Linked organisations</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <tr align="left">
          <th> Code </th>
          <th> Name </th>
          <th> Description </th>
          <th> Updated by </th>
          <th> Updated at </th>
        </tr>
        <%@organisation.child_orgs.each do |child_org| %>
        <tr align="left">
          <td valign="top"> <%=link_to child_org.code, child_org%> </td>
          <td valign="top"> <%=child_org.name%> </td>
          <td class="col_wide"> <%=child_org.description%> </td>
          <td valign="top"> <%=child_org.updated_by%> </td>
          <td valign="top"> <%=child_org.updated_at%> </td>
        </tr>
        <% end%>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Add organisation', new_organisation_child_org_path(@organisation) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get the message: **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Organisations#show** as the SQL generated refers an organisations.organisation_id column that does not exist:

```
SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations"  WHERE "organisations"."organisation_id" = ?
```

**My questions:**

1 - How can I avoir this error?

2 - Is the new_organisation_child_org_path(@organisation) path correct for creating a child organisation?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify foreign_key on has_many association:

```
has_many :child_orgs, :class_name => "Organisation" , :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case tou'd better use a finder_sql or a scope depending which version of rails you use to select child organizations to avoid to add child_id attribute to your organisations table.

in organization.rb

Rails 3

```
has_many :child_orgs, class_name: "Organization", finder_sql: proc { "SELECT * FROM organizations WHERE parent_id = #{id}" }
```

Rails 4 (not tested)

```
has_many :child_orgs, ->(id) { where(parent_id: id) }, class_name: "Organization"
```

for the route you need to call

```
new_organization_organizations_path(@organization)
```

type in console `rake routes` to see all available routes

Comment: sry using a buldozer for smth simple :) you just missed the foreign_key attribute in has_many

Comment: I think for Rails 4, the ->{} bit has to be before the class_name: bit. But even if I put it that way around, I get an error about id being undefined...